why istringstream tie with ostringstream invalid
auto main() -> int {
  istringstream is;
  ostringstream os;
  is.tie(&os);

  string name = "hello";
  os << name;
  string newName;
  is >> newName;

  cout << newName << endl;
}

I think the console will display 'hello', but it is indeed empty

tie just causes flush calls, it doesn't transfer data between streams.

@interjay The code was written with reference to the following link ，I want to why my example run fail https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie

If you're talking about the example shown in that link, that works because both streams are accessing the same file, so flushing the output stream means the input stream can now read the data from the file.

Oh well C++ never fails.
Why there is an issue with your code.
tie operation is intended to help sync output and input streams. simply because it ties(from the word tie) the istringstream (is) to the ostringstream (os). But it's not under any obligation to allow data streaming transfer between both. However, it only ensures that any flushed output from os will occur before any subsequent input operation on is.
To buttress interkjay's comment.
What you want is to transfer the data from os to is and then read it back into newName, you need to explicitly assign the data from os to is:
os.str() recieves the "string" stores it in the ostringstream.
Then is.str(os.str()) helps sets the data of the istringstream to be the same data as the "string" you earlier stored in os
C++ lawyers might have better solution...
Another alternative as alluded to by @Ted-Lyngmo is:

If OP makes os a std::stringstream, swapping std::streambufs may be an
alternative you could mention.

Here is how to get the result you want:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  istringstream is;
  ostringstream os;

  string name = "hello";
  os << name;

  // Transfer the data from os to is
  is.str(os.str());

  string newName;
  is >> newName;

  cout << newName << endl;

  return 0;
}


If OP makes os a std::stringstream, swapping std::streambufs may be an alternative you could mention too. example

@TedLyngmo spot on! perhaps we can do some benchmarking haha!

:-) Yeah, fire it up in quick-bench to measure. I suspect that buffer-swapping will be slower for strings with SSO but faster if SSO is not in effect. Just a hunch, I haven't measured.

coughs clears throats drums rolling :D  https://quick-bench.com/q/XHaN7669HKHkO9AUwPNis5N5O-M

You are missing measuring in that benchmarking though.

I have update the question, could u pls explain it?

@TedLyngmo my bad occupation hazard  :-) will redo

hi @xunhaohw what do you need me to explain? why your code works or why it doesn't?

@xunhaohw Please don't change your question so that answers that you've gotten to it suddenly does not seem to answer your question. Derek's answer answered your original question so be happy with that. If you have another question, then please post that separately. I rolled back the changes that you did to your question.

@xunhaohw As rightfully said by Ted, you should always ask only one question on stackoverflow. if you feel your question has been answered you can close it and accept any answers that has helped you understand your problem. There is no limit to the number of questions, you can ask provided readers can understand, if not you would be quickly introduced to down-voting or worse your question closed haha! . Most importantly I hope I and Ted's answers have been meaningful.

The root cause of this problem is that the is stream is empty. When a link is established between is and os, this linking operation only flushes a buffer in the os stream, but no data is automatically transferred to is.
First fill the os object. Then give os to the is object. Finally, you will see "hello".
#include <iostream>     
#include <sstream>      
#include <string>       

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int {
  ostringstream os;
  string name = "hello";
  os << name;
  istringstream is(os.str());
  string newName;
  is >> newName;

  cout << newName << endl;
}

